# Jaccard distance between tweets

Tags: json, r, twitter, set, stringdist

I'm currently trying to measure the Jaccard Distance between tweets in a dataset

This is where the dataset is

http://www3.nd.edu/~dwang5/courses/spring15/assignments/A2/Tweets.json

I've tried a few things to measure the distance

This is what I have so far

I saved the linked dataset to a file called Tweets.json

```
json_alldata <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(file("Tweets.json")),collapse=",")))
```

Then I converted json_alldata  to tweet.features and got rid of the geo column

```
# get rid of geo column
tweet.features = json_alldata
tweet.features$geo <- NULL
```

These are what the first two tweets look like

```
tweet.features$text[1]
[1] "RT @ItsJennaMarbles: Reports of Marathon Runners that crossed finish line and continued to run to Mass General Hospital to give blood to victims. #PrayforBoston"
> tweet.features$text[2]
[1] "RT @NBCSN: Reports of Marathon Runners that crossed finish line and continued to run to Mass General Hospital to give blood to victims #PrayforBoston"
```

First thing I tried was using the method `stringdist` which is under the stringdist library

```
install.packages("stringdist")
library(stringdist)

#This works?
#
stringdist(tweet.features$text[1], tweet.features$text[2], method = "jaccard")
```

When I run that, I get

[1] 0.1621622

I'm not sure that's correct, though.    A intersection B = 23, and A union B = 25.   The Jaccard distance is A intersection B/A union B -- right?  So by my calculation, the Jaccard distance should be 0.92?

So I figured I could do it by sets.  Simply calculate intersection and union and divide

This is what I tried

```
# Jaccard distance is the intersection of A and B divided by the Union of A and B
#
#create set for First Tweet
A1 <- as.set(tweet.features$text[1])
A2 <- as.set(tweet.features$text[2])
```

When I try to do intersection, I get this:  The output is just list()

```
 Intersection <- intersect(A1, A2)
 list()
```

When I try Union, I get this:

union(A1, A2)

```
[[1]]
[1] "RT @ItsJennaMarbles: Reports of Marathon Runners that crossed finish line and continued to run to Mass General Hospital to give blood to victims. #PrayforBoston"

[[2]]
[1] "RT @NBCSN: Reports of Marathon Runners that crossed finish line and continued to run to Mass General Hospital to give blood to victims #PrayforBoston"
```

This doesn't seem to be grouping the words into a single set.

I figured I'd be able to divide the intersection by the union.  But I guess I would need the program to count the number or words in each set, then do the calculations.

Needless to say, I'm a bit stuck and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `0.1621622` is the distance in terms of `1 - length( intersect(colnames(qgrams(tweet.features$text[1])),colnames(qgrams(tweet.features$text[2]))) ) / length( unique(c(colnames(qgrams(tweet.features$text[1])), colnames(qgrams(tweet.features$text[2])))) )`. You are free to build n-grams or tokenize your tweets. I don't know what you want in the end.

Comment: Thank you.  So I guess that function I ran is this long line of code?  I'm trying to measure the number of words in each tweet, then calculate the Jaccard distance.   It would probably be easier if I picked two very different tweets.  The ones I picked are very similar to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intersect` and `union` expect vectors (`as.set` does not exist). I think you want to compare words so you can use `strsplit` but the way the split is done belongs to you. An example below:

```
tweet.features <- list(tweet1="RT @ItsJennaMarbles: Reports of Marathon Runners that crossed finish line and continued to run to Mass General Hospital to give blood to victims. #PrayforBoston",
                       tweet2=          "RT @NBCSN: Reports of Marathon Runners that crossed finish line and continued to run to Mass General Hospital to give blood to victims #PrayforBoston")

jaccard_i <- function(tw1, tw2){
  tw1 <- unlist(strsplit(tw1, " |\\."))
  tw2 <- unlist(strsplit(tw2, " |\\."))
  i <- length(intersect(tw1, tw2))
  u <- length(union(tw1, tw2))
  list(i=i, u=u, j=i/u)
}

jaccard_i(tweet.features[[1]], tweet.features[[2]])

$i
[1] 20

$u
[1] 23

$j
[1] 0.8695652
```

Is this want you want?

The `strsplit` is here done for every space or dot. You may want to refine the `split` argument from `strsplit` and replace `" |\\."` for something more specific (see `?regex`).

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like it'll be really helpful.  I'll test it out tonight.    So the strssplit is measuring the spaces, but I guess it's the same thing as counting the number of words?

Comment: Well, it mostly depends on your question. Not an expert of text analysis but there are some here.

Comment: I tested it out.  It works really well.  What I'm trying to do is cluster tweets with the K-means algorithm based on their Jaccard Distance.  So I guess I need to modify it and figure out how to test the Jaccard distance across 251 tweets.

Comment: nice + you can do it ;-)

Comment: We'll see.  I hope so :P

Comment: I decided to modify the algorithm you provided a bit, but I'm not sure if I should ask a question here, or start a new question.  I basically edited the tweet.features <- list line to select 10 random tweets from the dataset.  But I think when I run the Jaccard distance, it's actually calculating the Jaccard by adding up all the tweets instead of comparing two tweets.

This is what I changed and left everything else the same

tweetText <- list(sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 5), sample(tweet.features$text, replace = FALSE, size = 5))